# C++/CLI UdpClient multithreaded pool

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli, udpclient

I start by saying this is my first multi-threaded software, so be polite :)

I have a multithreaded application written in C++/CLI which uses a pool of UdpClient to read from/write to an external hardware.

Basically, there are three threads: a *receiving thread*, which manages the reception of messages incoming from the external hardware and puts them in a parsing queue, a *parsing thread* which checks the correctness of the received messages and generates a proper response which is put in a sending queue, and a *sending thread* which continuously checks the sending queue to send the enqueued messages to the external hardware.

As for the UdpClients, I use two of them: a *receiving client* for the reception of incoming messages, and a *sending client* to send the responses: this is due to the fact that the external hardware can change its IP address at runtime, so the receiving UdpClient has to listen on any IP addresses, while the sending client should send the datagram to the specific IP address of the external hardware. Furthermore, the receiving client has a  timeout value which allows to control the connection status of the external hardware.

Here I show some example code for the receiving thread:

```
// Receiving thread
UdpClient^ receivingClient = gcnew UdpClient(IPAddress::Any, 30303);
// Set a timeout
receivingClient->Client->ReceiveTimeout = 3000;
// Iteratively receive on IP::Any and 30303
while(true)    
{
    try
    {
        array<Byte>^ recMessage = receivingClient->Receive();
        // Put the message in the parsing queue, which is a global object
        parQueue->Enqueue(recMessage);
    }
    catch (SocketException^ ex)
    {
        // Handle timeout exception
    }
}
```

Please note I get the exact IP address of the external hardware from the IPEndPoint of the receiving client, and I put it in a global variable called `ExternalHardwareIP`.

And here's some example code for the parsing thread:

```
while(true)
{
     if(parQueue->Count > 0)
     {
         // Method that parse message and puts it in the sending queue
         ParseMessage(parQueue->Dequeue());
     }
}
```

Finally, here's some example code for the sending thread:

```
UdpClient^ sendingClient = gcnew UdpClient(ExternalHardwareIp, 30303);
while(true)
{
    if(senQueue->Count > 0)
    {
        sendingClient->Send(senQueue->Dequeue());
    }
}
```

Now, I think there are several problems with this approach, as it appears that the sending operation on the sending thread is blocking the whole application, preventing the receiving thread to receive any message from the external hardware, and causing me some headaches.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: There are a *lot* of problems with this code.  At breakneck speed, your queue is not thread-safe and requires locking, your transmit thread is burning 100% core and getting very little done, you have no good way to get your program shut down, there is no meaningful way to handle a timeout other then just trying again, UDP is not connection oriented.  Get ahead by not creating your own threads.  Use UdpClient.Send() to take advantage of the buffering that the OS provides.  And BeginReceive() to minimize the dangers of threading.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions; I see I had to specify this is not the real code, but rather a simplification. However, I use a ConcurrentQueue, as it is thread safe according to MSDN, the shut down of the program is actually managed in the real code and the SocketException due to the timeout is handled. I am honestly thinking about two ways to handle the threading dangers: use both BeginSend and BeginReceive, or switch to the underlying Sockets.